# Adding a third light circuit onto existing

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I have included a diagram of my current basement lighting setup - this is how the house was built.

Switches 1/2 control Light 1, Switch 3 controls Light 2.

I would like to add Light 3, and Switches 4/5.

Switch 3 would be replaced with a 3-way switch, and Switch 3 and Switch 4 would control Light 2.

Light 3 will be controlled by Switch 5 only.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: what is the physical distance from sw 4 and 5 to sw 3 ? how will you bring power to sw 4&5 ?

Comment: It would be about 10 feet of wire. Switch 1 is at the top of the stairs, Switch 2/3 are outside the door to the basement and switch 4/5 would be inside

Comment: Can you reorganize your diagram so that the switches are organized by which boxes they're in?

Comment: Or if that is already so, how the cables are routed?

Answer (score 2):

Can't do it in 1 cable.  Unless it's /4 or smart switches.

### If you want traditional 3-way

then you will need 4 wires +ground to the new box: Always-hot and 2 travelers for the 3-way, and always-hot+neutral for the plain switch.

Each cable must have equal/opposite/balanced current in it.  All current that runs up 1 wire of a cable must return on one of the other wires in the same cable.  NEC 300.3 and to avoid throwing magnetic fields, vibration, cracking, eddy current heating.

So 2 cables physically (but not functionally!) in parallel. One /3 for the trad 3-way and one /2 for the new switch.

Alternately you could use the obscure /4 cable, with red and blue as travelers.  (or red and white/red if you use the even more obscure /2/2).

### With smart switches

that have the ability to use powerline-coded or radio communication between them, you only need the aforementioned /2 cable to deliver always-hot and neutral to the solo switch.   The smart remote can simply grab that always-hot and neutral to power itself.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way depending on location of the switch and light is to run a cable from the white and black boxes(junction) to the switch then to the light.

If easier to run the power to the light first, then need a three wire cable(plus ground) to the switch from the light, so you have a neutral wire(unused and capped) at the switch for the newer code.

Make sure you turn off the breaker and check there is no power, with a non contact tester or a multi-meter, before working on the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Safety first when working with killer voltage.

Those are multiple projects.
First replace sw3 & sw4 with 3-way switches.

3 way switches have 3 wires on them.

Two wires are used as travelers (switched hot) between the switches and one wire on each switch is either input or output depending on switch location. If you choose the sw3 to be the input then the permanent hot will go in that one. The two travelers will then bring it to the SW4 depending on the switch position. SW4 will have the two traveler and one switched output that goes to the lamp. Now you can turn on/off the lamp from either of the switches.

Switch 5 is a standard switch. It need one hot input that is then switched going out to the lamp.

You will also have to bring a non-switched neutrals to the lamps.